# Killing a query with a timed thread

Tags: python, mysql, timer, execute

I want to kill a running query with a time thread. I've experimented with different implementations and nothing seems to work.

Right now I call the function executeTimedQuery, which starts off a ten second timer that gets executed if a query is taking too long to run. At the start self.cursor.execute(self.query) gets run, which is the long running query that I want to kill after 10 seconds. For some reason, even though the function in the timer gets kicked off, the cursor is still running the long running query and does not run KILL CONNECTION {pId};. It waits for the long query to finish before killing the connection at the end.

What am I doing wrong here and what is the best way to fix it? I'm pretty desperate at the moment for a solution. :/

So far I have the following code:

```
def killDBConnection(self, processId):
  '''
  This takes in a processId, which is the mysql cursor connection process 
  id.
  '''
  killQuery = 'KILL CONNECTION {pId};'.format(pId=processId)
  try:
    self.cursor.execute(killQuery)
  except:
    print('Testing')
  return 'temp'


def executeTimedQuery(self, ret):
  '''
  This takes in a dictionary.
  '''
  pID =  self.getProcessId()
  try:
    Timer(10.0, self.killDBConnection, [pID]).start()
    self.cursor.execute(self.query)
    ret['executable'] = True
    ret['data'] = self.cursor.fetchall()
    ret['headers'] = tuple([col[0] for col in self.cursor.description])
    t.cancel()
  except:
    print('executeTimedQuery - Last executed query: ', self.cursor._last_executed)
  return ret
```

Comment: Not sure about all the implementation details, but it seems like running another `execute` on the same cursor just gets the request queued while the previous query is still busying the socket or how they talk to each other. That said, I suppose you need to resort to other means to actually kill the underlying connection (and start a new one; of if feasible, start query with a connection, on a new thread (in a process) and kill that off when timed out.

Comment: @OndrejK. Thank you. The reason you described was why this was failing. After I posted the question I ended up opening up a new connection for the KILL query and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

The example I have above kept failing because I was trying to execute a 'KILL PID' query on the same mysql thread that was still processing the long running query. The 'KILL PID' was run only after the long running query finished, which is not what I wanted. Long story short, the way to kill a long running query is to open up another connection shoot down the long running query with 'KILL PID'. Now getting the right PID is essential before you even execute the long running query.

Initially, I wrote a class that initialized one connection and cursor and was accessible anywhere within the function. Instead of doing this, I just wrote a function that could create connections for me when called. I initialized a connection for the long running query and one for the kill query function. I got the process ID from the long running query, and then used a timed thread to start the 'KILL PID' after a certain amount of time.

Here is a skeleton/most of the code:

```
class QueryWithTimeout(object):
  def __init__(self, db, query, totalTimeout):
    self.db = db
    self.query = query
    self.totalTimeout = totalTimeout
    ...

  def setUpConnection(self):
    connection = connections[self.db]
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return cursor, connection

  def getProcessId(self, cursor):
    processID = 'SELECT CONNECTION_ID();'
    cursor.execute(processID)
    processIDOutput = cursor.fetchall()[0]
    return processIDOutput[0]

  def killDBConnection(self, processId, ret):
    killCursor, killConnection = self.setUpConnection()
    killQuery = 'KILL {pId};'.format(pId=processId)
    try:
      killCursor.execute(killQuery)
    except:
      print('TEMP')

  def executeTimedQuery(self, pId, cursor):
    ret = {...}
    timeoutCall = Timer(self.totalTimeout, self.killDBConnection, [pId, ret])
    timeoutCall.start()
    try:
      cursor.execute(self.query)
      #timeoutCall.cancel()
    except:
      return ret
  ret[...] = ...
  return ret

  def processTimedQuery(self):
    queryCursor, queryConnection = self.setUpConnection()
    queryProcessId = self.getProcessId(queryCursor)
    return self.executeTimedQuery(queryProcessId, queryCursor)
```

As a side note, I tried all kinds of things and everything failed, but this.